# How to make this slider automatic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a manual slider, but i want to make the sliders autoplay. I use the data position to make each slide come to the front when you press the slider / buttons. How can i do that without modify all the js? Or if you can help me with a same slider, but just to be automatic? Any solution is welcome.

[Here is my code](https://codepen.io/CosminAndrei2000/pen/abbgXgG)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    function detect_active() {
        // get active
        var get_active = $("#dp-slider .dp_item:first-child").data("class");
        $("#dp-dots li").removeClass("active");
        $("#dp-dots li[data-class=" + get_active + "]").addClass("active");
    }

    $("#dp-dots li").click(function () {
        $("#dp-dots li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        var get_slide = $(this).attr('data-class');
        $("#dp-slider .dp_item[data-class=" + get_slide + "]").hide().prependTo("#dp-slider").fadeIn();
        $.each($('#slider .dp_item'), function (index, dp_item) {
            $(dp_item).attr('data-position', index + 1);
        });
    });


    $("body").on("click", "#dp-slider .dp_item:not(:first-child)", function () {
        var get_slide = $(this).attr('data-class');
        $("#dp-slider .dp_item[data-class=" + get_slide + "]").hide().prependTo("#dp-slider").fadeIn();
        $.each($('#slider .dp_item'), function (index, dp_item) {
            $(dp_item).attr('data-position', index + 1);
        });

        detect_active();
    });
    $("#dp-dots .first,#dp-slider .item-1").click(function () {
        $(".div-1").addClass('is-active');
        $(".item-1 .dp-content").addClass('opacity');
        $(".item-1 .dp-content img").addClass('fade-up');
        $(".item-2 .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
        $(".item-2 .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');
        $(".item-3 .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
        $(".item-3 .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');
        $(".div-2").removeClass('is-active');
        $(".div-3").removeClass('is-active');
    });

    $("#dp-dots .second, .item-2").click(function () {
        $(".div-1").removeClass('is-active');
        $(".item-1 .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
        $(".item-1 .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');
        $(".item-2 .dp-content").addClass('opacity');
        $(".item-2 .dp-content img").addClass('fade-up');
        $(".item-3 .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
        $(".item-3 .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');
        $(".div-3").removeClass('is-active');
        $(".div-2").addClass('is-active');
    });

    $("#dp-dots .third, .item-3").click(function () {
        $(".div-1").removeClass('is-active');
        $(".item-1 .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
        $(".item-1 .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');
        $(".item-2 .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
        $(".item-2 .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');
        $(".item-3 .dp-content").addClass('opacity');
        $(".item-3 .dp-content img").addClass('fade-up');
        $(".div-2").removeClass('is-active');
        $(".div-3").addClass('is-active');
    });

});
```

```css
#home .content-slider {
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: -100px;
}

#home .text {
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

#home .div-1, #home .div-2, #home .div-3 {
    opacity: 0;
    left: -1000px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

#home .is-active {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 160px;
}

#home .div-1, #home .div-2, #home .div-3 {
    text-align: right;
}

#home .div-1 h1, #home .div-2 h1, #home .div-3 h1 {
    font-family: Raleway-black;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#home .div-1 p, #home .div-2 p, #home .div-3 p {
    font-family: Raleway-semi-bold;
    color: #333333;
}

#home .extra-bold {
    font-family: Raleway-extra-bold;
}

#home #slider {
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

#home .dp-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 750px;
}

#home #dp-slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
}

#home #slider .dp_item {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: transform 1.2s;

}

#home #slider .dp-content {
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
}

#home #slider .item-1 {
    background-color: #cf132a;
}

#home .opacity {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

#home #slider .item-1 img, #home #slider .item-2 img, #home #slider .item-3 img {
    width: 300px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 20px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
    margin-left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;

}

#home .fade-up {
    top: 5px !important;
}

#home #slider .item-1 .absolute, #home #slider .item-2 .absolute, #home #slider .item-3 .absolute {
    font-family: Raleway-black;
    color: #a2a2a2;
    opacity: 0.33;
    position: absolute;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

#home #slider .item-1 .line-1 {
    bottom: -60px;
    right: 30px;
}

#home #slider .item-1 .line-2 {
    bottom: -100px;
    right: -10px;
}

#home #slider .item-2 .line-1 {
    bottom: -60px;
    right: 20px;
}

#home #slider .item-2 .line-2 {
    bottom: -100px;
    right: 0;
}

#home #slider .item-3 .line-1 {
    bottom: -60px;
    right: 50px;
}

#home #slider .item-3 .line-2 {
    bottom: -100px;
    right: 0;
}

#home #slider .item-2 {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

#home #slider .item-3 {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#home #dp-slider .dp_item:first-child {
    z-index: 10 !important;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px) !important;
}

#home #slider .dp_item[data-position="2"] {
    z-index: 9;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(10%) translateY(-15%) scale(0.9);
}

#home .transform {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(10%) translateY(-15%) scale(0.9) !important;
}

#home #slider .dp_item[data-position="3"] {
    z-index: 8;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(20%) translateY(-25%) scale(0.8);
}


#home #dp-dots {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    z-index: 12;
    right: 30px;
    cursor: default;
    padding: 0;
}

#home #dp-dots li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 9px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 3px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    cursor: pointer;
}

#home #dp-dots .first {
    height: 55px;
}

#home #dp-dots .second {
    height: 45px;
}

#home #dp-dots .third {
    height: 35px;
}

#home #dp-dots li.active {
    background: #cf132a;
}

#home #slider .dp_item {
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 750px;
    height: 280px;
}


#home #dp-slider .dp_item:hover:not(:first-child) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home">
<div class="content-slider">
                <div class="text">
                    <div class="div div-1 is-active" data-class="1" data-position="1">
                        <h1>The New Hydra.VOX</h1>
                        <p>With state-of-the-art tech the VOX is the newest generation of Audiobyte D/A Converters, the
                            result of years of research.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="div div-2" data-class="2" data-position="2">
                        <h1>The New Hydra.HUB</h1>
                        <p>The next step towards the ultimate Audio Stack – the hub packs enhanced audio transport
                            capability with a set of digital tools for even the most demanding user.</p>
                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="div div-3" data-class="3" data-position="3">
                        <h1>The Hydra.ZAP Power Supply</h1>
                        <p>The ZAP is the dedicated, low-noise ultra-capacitor based power supply for the VOX HUB stack.
                            Attain supreme control over your digital equipment.</p>
     
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="slider">
                    <div class="dp-wrap">
                        <div id="dp-slider">
                            <div class="dp_item item-1" data-class="1" data-position="1">
                                <div class="dp-content opacity">
                                    <img class="fade-up" src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/6/Amplifier-PNG-File.png" alt="">
                                    <h1 class="absolute line-1">SUPREME IMMERSION</h1>
                                    <h1 class="absolute line-2">CONTEMPORARY DESIGN</h1>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dp_item item-2" data-class="2" data-position="2">
                                <div class="dp-content">
                                    <img class="fade-up" src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/6/Amplifier-PNG-File.png" alt="">
                                    <h1 class="absolute line-1">VERSATILITY</h1>
                                    <h1 class="absolute line-2">DIGITAL MASTERY</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="dp_item item-3" data-class="3" data-position="3">
                                <div class="dp-content">
                                    <img class="fade-up" src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/6/Amplifier-PNG-File.png" alt="">
                                    <h1 class="absolute line-1">HIGH PERFORMANCE</h1>
                                    <h1 class="absolute line-2">NO COMPROMISE</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <ul id="dp-dots">
                            <li data-class="1" class="active first"></li>
                            <li data-class="2" class="second"></li>
                            <li data-class="3" class="third"></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: In your case it looks like triggering clicks on the buttons in an interval would be the best solution. Other solutions would require a lot of changes to the existing code.

Comment: Can you give me an example of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to create a general function for both clicks and autoplay (that I created using a `setInterval`).

I decided to use your `get_slide` variable to switch to active `li` or `slide`.

These are my changes:

```
var num = 1; // a variable to set the actual active slider

$("#dp-dots li, #dp-slider .dp_item").click(function() {
    var get_slide = $(this).attr('data-class');
    num = get_slide
    generalClick(get_slide);
});


function generalClick(number) {
    $("#dp-dots li").removeClass("active");
    $("#dp-dots li:nth-child(" + number + ")").addClass("active");
    $("#dp-slider .dp_item[data-class=" + number + "]").hide().prependTo("#dp-slider").fadeIn();
    $.each($('#slider .dp_item'), function(index, dp_item) {
        $(dp_item).attr('data-position', index + 1);
    });

    $(".text .div").removeClass('is-active');
    $(".div-" + number).addClass('is-active');

    $(".dp_item .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
    $(".dp_item .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');

    $(".item-" + number + " .dp-content").addClass('opacity');
    $(".item-" + number + " .dp-content img").addClass('fade-up');
}

setInterval(function() {
    num++
    if (num > $("#dp-dots li").length) {
        num = 1;
    }
    generalClick(num);
}, 5000);
```

The code at work (I commented on yours that I didn't use):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    
    function detect_active() {
        // get active
        var get_active = $("#dp-slider .dp_item:first-child").data("class");
        $("#dp-dots li").removeClass("active");
        $("#dp-dots li[data-class=" + get_active + "]").addClass("active");
    }

    var num=1;
    
    $("#dp-dots li, #dp-slider .dp_item").click(function () {
        /*$("#dp-dots li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");*/
        
        /*$("#dp-slider .dp_item[data-class=" + get_slide + "]").hide().prependTo("#dp-slider").fadeIn();*/
        var get_slide = $(this).attr('data-class');
        num=get_slide
        generalClick(get_slide);

    });

    function generalClick(number){
        $("#dp-dots li").removeClass("active");
        $("#dp-dots li:nth-child("+number+")").addClass("active");
        $("#dp-slider .dp_item[data-class=" + number + "]").hide().prependTo("#dp-slider").fadeIn();
        $.each($('#slider .dp_item'), function (index, dp_item) {
            $(dp_item).attr('data-position', index + 1);
        });

        $(".text .div").removeClass('is-active');
        $(".div-"+ number).addClass('is-active');

        $(".dp_item .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
        $(".dp_item .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');

        $(".item-"+ number +" .dp-content").addClass('opacity');
        $(".item-"+ number +" .dp-content img").addClass('fade-up');
    }

    setInterval( function() { 
        num ++
        if(num > $("#dp-dots li").length){
            num=1;
        }
        generalClick(num); 
    }, 5000 );


    $("body").on("click", "#dp-slider .dp_item:not(:first-child)", function () {
        var get_slide = $(this).attr('data-class');
        $("#dp-slider .dp_item[data-class=" + get_slide + "]").hide().prependTo("#dp-slider").fadeIn();
        $.each($('#slider .dp_item'), function (index, dp_item) {
            $(dp_item).attr('data-position', index + 1);
        });

        detect_active();
    });


    /*$("#dp-dots .first,#dp-slider .item-1").click(function () {
        $(".div-1").addClass('is-active');
        $(".item-1 .dp-content").addClass('opacity');
        $(".item-1 .dp-content img").addClass('fade-up');
        $(".item-2 .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
        $(".item-2 .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');
        $(".item-3 .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
        $(".item-3 .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');
        $(".div-2").removeClass('is-active');
        $(".div-3").removeClass('is-active');
    });

    $("#dp-dots .second, .item-2").click(function () {
        $(".div-1").removeClass('is-active');
        $(".item-1 .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
        $(".item-1 .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');
        $(".item-2 .dp-content").addClass('opacity');
        $(".item-2 .dp-content img").addClass('fade-up');
        $(".item-3 .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
        $(".item-3 .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');
        $(".div-3").removeClass('is-active');
        $(".div-2").addClass('is-active');
    });

    $("#dp-dots .third, .item-3").click(function () {
        $(".div-1").removeClass('is-active');
        $(".item-1 .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
        $(".item-1 .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');
        $(".item-2 .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
        $(".item-2 .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');
        $(".item-3 .dp-content").addClass('opacity');
        $(".item-3 .dp-content img").addClass('fade-up');
        $(".div-2").removeClass('is-active');
        $(".div-3").addClass('is-active');
    });*/
});
```

```css
#home .content-slider {
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: -100px;
}

#home .text {
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

#home .div-1, #home .div-2, #home .div-3 {
    opacity: 0;
    left: -1000px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

#home .is-active {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 160px;
}

#home .div-1, #home .div-2, #home .div-3 {
    text-align: right;
}

#home .div-1 h1, #home .div-2 h1, #home .div-3 h1 {
    font-family: Raleway-black;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#home .div-1 p, #home .div-2 p, #home .div-3 p {
    font-family: Raleway-semi-bold;
    color: #333333;
}

#home .extra-bold {
    font-family: Raleway-extra-bold;
}

#home #slider {
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

#home .dp-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 750px;
}

#home #dp-slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
}

#home #slider .dp_item {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: transform 1.2s;

}

#home #slider .dp-content {
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
}

#home #slider .item-1 {
    background-color: #cf132a;
}

#home .opacity {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

#home #slider .item-1 img, #home #slider .item-2 img, #home #slider .item-3 img {
    width: 300px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 20px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
    margin-left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;

}

#home .fade-up {
    top: 5px !important;
}

#home #slider .item-1 .absolute, #home #slider .item-2 .absolute, #home #slider .item-3 .absolute {
    font-family: Raleway-black;
    color: #a2a2a2;
    opacity: 0.33;
    position: absolute;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

#home #slider .item-1 .line-1 {
    bottom: -60px;
    right: 30px;
}

#home #slider .item-1 .line-2 {
    bottom: -100px;
    right: -10px;
}

#home #slider .item-2 .line-1 {
    bottom: -60px;
    right: 20px;
}

#home #slider .item-2 .line-2 {
    bottom: -100px;
    right: 0;
}

#home #slider .item-3 .line-1 {
    bottom: -60px;
    right: 50px;
}

#home #slider .item-3 .line-2 {
    bottom: -100px;
    right: 0;
}

#home #slider .item-2 {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

#home #slider .item-3 {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#home #dp-slider .dp_item:first-child {
    z-index: 10 !important;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px) !important;
}

#home #slider .dp_item[data-position="2"] {
    z-index: 9;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(10%) translateY(-15%) scale(0.9);
}

#home .transform {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(10%) translateY(-15%) scale(0.9) !important;
}

#home #slider .dp_item[data-position="3"] {
    z-index: 8;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(20%) translateY(-25%) scale(0.8);
}


#home #dp-dots {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    z-index: 12;
    right: 30px;
    cursor: default;
    padding: 0;
}

#home #dp-dots li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 9px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 3px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    cursor: pointer;
}

#home #dp-dots .first {
    height: 55px;
}

#home #dp-dots .second {
    height: 45px;
}

#home #dp-dots .third {
    height: 35px;
}

#home #dp-dots li.active {
    background: #cf132a;
}

#home #slider .dp_item {
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 750px;
    height: 280px;
}


#home #dp-slider .dp_item:hover:not(:first-child) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home">
   <div class="content-slider">
      <div class="text">
         <div class="div div-1 is-active" data-class="1" data-position="1">
            <h1>The New Hydra.VOX</h1>
            <p>With state-of-the-art tech the VOX is the newest generation of Audiobyte D/A Converters, the
               result of years of research.
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="div div-2" data-class="2" data-position="2">
            <h1>The New Hydra.HUB</h1>
            <p>The next step towards the ultimate Audio Stack – the hub packs enhanced audio transport
               capability with a set of digital tools for even the most demanding user.
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="div div-3" data-class="3" data-position="3">
            <h1>The Hydra.ZAP Power Supply</h1>
            <p>The ZAP is the dedicated, low-noise ultra-capacitor based power supply for the VOX HUB stack.
               Attain supreme control over your digital equipment.
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="slider">
         <div class="dp-wrap">
            <div id="dp-slider">
               <div class="dp_item item-1" data-class="1" data-position="1">
                  <div class="dp-content opacity">
                     <img class="fade-up" src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/6/Amplifier-PNG-File.png" alt="">
                     <h1 class="absolute line-1">SUPREME IMMERSION</h1>
                     <h1 class="absolute line-2">CONTEMPORARY DESIGN</h1>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dp_item item-2" data-class="2" data-position="2">
                  <div class="dp-content">
                     <img class="fade-up" src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/6/Amplifier-PNG-File.png" alt="">
                     <h1 class="absolute line-1">VERSATILITY</h1>
                     <h1 class="absolute line-2">DIGITAL MASTERY</h1>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dp_item item-3" data-class="3" data-position="3">
                  <div class="dp-content">
                     <img class="fade-up" src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/6/Amplifier-PNG-File.png" alt="">
                     <h1 class="absolute line-1">HIGH PERFORMANCE</h1>
                     <h1 class="absolute line-2">NO COMPROMISE</h1>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <ul id="dp-dots">
               <li data-class="1" class="active first"></li>
               <li data-class="2" class="second"></li>
               <li data-class="3" class="third"></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT1**

To stop the interval when you enter with mouse in slider stage I did these changes:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);

function myTimer() {
  num ++
  if(num > $("#dp-dots li").length){
    num=1;
  }
  generalClick(num); 
}

$(".content-slider").on("mouseenter", function() {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
    myInterval = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);
});
```

**EDIT 2**

To stop the click action on the active element you can work with a simple conditional statement:

```
$("#dp-dots li, #dp-slider .dp_item").click(function() {
     var get_slide = $(this).attr('data-class');
     num=get_slide
     if($(this).attr('data-position')!=1){
        generalClick(get_slide);
     }
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var num=1;

    $("#dp-dots li, #dp-slider .dp_item").click(function() {
        var get_slide = $(this).attr('data-class');
        num=get_slide
        if($(this).attr('data-position')!=1){
            generalClick(get_slide);
         }
    });


    function generalClick(number){
        $("#dp-dots li").removeClass("active");
        $("#dp-dots li:nth-child("+number+")").addClass("active");
        $("#dp-slider .dp_item[data-class=" + number + "]").hide().prependTo("#dp-slider").fadeIn();
        $.each($('#slider .dp_item'), function (index, dp_item) {
            $(dp_item).attr('data-position', index + 1);
        });

        $(".text .div").removeClass('is-active');
        $(".div-"+ number).addClass('is-active');

        $(".dp_item .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
        $(".dp_item .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');

        $(".item-"+ number +" .dp-content").addClass('opacity');
        $(".item-"+ number +" .dp-content img").addClass('fade-up');
    }

    var myInterval = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);

    function myTimer() {
      num ++
      if(num > $("#dp-dots li").length){
        num=1;
      }
      generalClick(num); 
    }

    $(".content-slider").on("mouseenter", function() {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        myInterval = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);
    });

});
```

```css
#home .content-slider {
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: -100px;
}

#home .text {
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

#home .div-1, #home .div-2, #home .div-3 {
    opacity: 0;
    left: -1000px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

#home .is-active {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 160px;
}

#home .div-1, #home .div-2, #home .div-3 {
    text-align: right;
}

#home .div-1 h1, #home .div-2 h1, #home .div-3 h1 {
    font-family: Raleway-black;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#home .div-1 p, #home .div-2 p, #home .div-3 p {
    font-family: Raleway-semi-bold;
    color: #333333;
}

#home .extra-bold {
    font-family: Raleway-extra-bold;
}

#home #slider {
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

#home .dp-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 750px;
}

#home #dp-slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
}

#home #slider .dp_item {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: transform 1.2s;

}

#home #slider .dp-content {
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
}

#home #slider .item-1 {
    background-color: #cf132a;
}

#home .opacity {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

#home #slider .item-1 img, #home #slider .item-2 img, #home #slider .item-3 img {
    width: 300px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 20px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
    margin-left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;

}

#home .fade-up {
    top: 5px !important;
}

#home #slider .item-1 .absolute, #home #slider .item-2 .absolute, #home #slider .item-3 .absolute {
    font-family: Raleway-black;
    color: #a2a2a2;
    opacity: 0.33;
    position: absolute;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

#home #slider .item-1 .line-1 {
    bottom: -60px;
    right: 30px;
}

#home #slider .item-1 .line-2 {
    bottom: -100px;
    right: -10px;
}

#home #slider .item-2 .line-1 {
    bottom: -60px;
    right: 20px;
}

#home #slider .item-2 .line-2 {
    bottom: -100px;
    right: 0;
}

#home #slider .item-3 .line-1 {
    bottom: -60px;
    right: 50px;
}

#home #slider .item-3 .line-2 {
    bottom: -100px;
    right: 0;
}

#home #slider .item-2 {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

#home #slider .item-3 {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#home #dp-slider .dp_item:first-child {
    z-index: 10 !important;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px) !important;
}

#home #slider .dp_item[data-position="2"] {
    z-index: 9;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(10%) translateY(-15%) scale(0.9);
}

#home .transform {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(10%) translateY(-15%) scale(0.9) !important;
}

#home #slider .dp_item[data-position="3"] {
    z-index: 8;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(20%) translateY(-25%) scale(0.8);
}


#home #dp-dots {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    z-index: 12;
    right: 30px;
    cursor: default;
    padding: 0;
}

#home #dp-dots li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 9px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 3px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    cursor: pointer;
}

#home #dp-dots .first {
    height: 55px;
}

#home #dp-dots .second {
    height: 45px;
}

#home #dp-dots .third {
    height: 35px;
}

#home #dp-dots li.active {
    background: #cf132a;
}

#home #slider .dp_item {
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 750px;
    height: 280px;
}


#home #dp-slider .dp_item:hover:not(:first-child) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home">
   <div class="content-slider">
      <div class="text">
         <div class="div div-1 is-active" data-class="1" data-position="1">
            <h1>The New Hydra.VOX</h1>
            <p>With state-of-the-art tech the VOX is the newest generation of Audiobyte D/A Converters, the
               result of years of research.
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="div div-2" data-class="2" data-position="2">
            <h1>The New Hydra.HUB</h1>
            <p>The next step towards the ultimate Audio Stack – the hub packs enhanced audio transport
               capability with a set of digital tools for even the most demanding user.
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="div div-3" data-class="3" data-position="3">
            <h1>The Hydra.ZAP Power Supply</h1>
            <p>The ZAP is the dedicated, low-noise ultra-capacitor based power supply for the VOX HUB stack.
               Attain supreme control over your digital equipment.
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="slider">
         <div class="dp-wrap">
            <div id="dp-slider">
               <div class="dp_item item-1" data-class="1" data-position="1">
                  <div class="dp-content opacity">
                     <img class="fade-up" src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/6/Amplifier-PNG-File.png" alt="">
                     <h1 class="absolute line-1">SUPREME IMMERSION</h1>
                     <h1 class="absolute line-2">CONTEMPORARY DESIGN</h1>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dp_item item-2" data-class="2" data-position="2">
                  <div class="dp-content">
                     <img class="fade-up" src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/6/Amplifier-PNG-File.png" alt="">
                     <h1 class="absolute line-1">VERSATILITY</h1>
                     <h1 class="absolute line-2">DIGITAL MASTERY</h1>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="dp_item item-3" data-class="3" data-position="3">
                  <div class="dp-content">
                     <img class="fade-up" src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/6/Amplifier-PNG-File.png" alt="">
                     <h1 class="absolute line-1">HIGH PERFORMANCE</h1>
                     <h1 class="absolute line-2">NO COMPROMISE</h1>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <ul id="dp-dots">
               <li data-class="1" class="active first"></li>
               <li data-class="2" class="second"></li>
               <li data-class="3" class="third"></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: YESS!! This is want i want! Thank you so much!

Comment: Can it be set that when the mouse is on the slide stop the slider?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is what i want to do!

Comment: Hello. I'm coming back with a little problem. How can I cancel the click for the active element? I ask because this is what happens when I press the div that comes in front. There is my problem: https://vimeo.com/378484003

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `setInterval` method to automate your slideshow.
For example, if you click a button and change the slide with event firing, call that method from setInterval starting from first index. And keep changing the value to make the slide show happen. I've created an example for you. (3 slides only)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var ch = 1;
    function detect_active() {
        // get active
        var get_active = $("#dp-slider .dp_item:first-child").data("class");
        $("#dp-dots li").removeClass("active");
        $("#dp-dots li[data-class=" + get_active + "]").addClass("active");
    } 
  function callClickEvent(){
    $("#dp-dots li").removeClass("active");
    var curCh = "ul li:nth-child("+ch+")";
        $(curCh).addClass("active");
        var get_slide = $(curCh).attr('data-class');
        $("#dp-slider .dp_item[data-class=" + get_slide + "]").hide().prependTo("#dp-slider").fadeIn();
    
        $('#slider .dp_item:nth-child('+ch+')').attr('data-position', ch);
    $(".div-"+ch+"").addClass('is-active');
        $(".item-"+ch+" .dp-content").addClass('opacity');
        $(".item-"+ch+" .dp-content img").addClass('fade-up');
    var r1 = r2 =0; 
    if(ch == 1) {r1 = 2; r2 = 3;}
    if(ch == 2) {r1 = 1; r2 = 3;}
    if(ch == 3) {r1 = 1; r2 = 2;}
        $(".item-"+r1+" .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
        $(".item-"+r1+" .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');
        $(".item-"+r2+" .dp-content").removeClass('opacity');
        $(".item-"+r2+" .dp-content img").removeClass('fade-up');
        $(".div-"+r1+"").removeClass('is-active');
        $(".div-"+r2+"").removeClass('is-active');
    ch++;
    if(ch>3) ch = 1;
  } 
  setInterval(callClickEvent,2000);

    $("body").on("click", "#dp-slider .dp_item:not(:first-child)", function () {
        var get_slide = $(this).attr('data-class');
        $("#dp-slider .dp_item[data-class=" + get_slide + "]").hide().prependTo("#dp-slider").fadeIn();
        $.each($('#slider .dp_item'), function (index, dp_item) {
            $(dp_item).attr('data-position', index + 1);
        });

        detect_active();
    });
});
```

```css
#home .content-slider {
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: -100px;
}

#home .text {
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

#home .div-1, #home .div-2, #home .div-3 {
    opacity: 0;
    left: -1000px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

#home .is-active {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 160px;
}

#home .div-1, #home .div-2, #home .div-3 {
    text-align: right;
}

#home .div-1 h1, #home .div-2 h1, #home .div-3 h1 {
    font-family: Raleway-black;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#home .div-1 p, #home .div-2 p, #home .div-3 p {
    font-family: Raleway-semi-bold;
    color: #333333;
}

#home .extra-bold {
    font-family: Raleway-extra-bold;
}

#home #slider {
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

#home .dp-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 750px;
}

#home #dp-slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
}

#home #slider .dp_item {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: transform 1.2s;

}

#home #slider .dp-content {
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
}

#home #slider .item-1 {
    background-color: #cf132a;
}

#home .opacity {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}

#home #slider .item-1 img, #home #slider .item-2 img, #home #slider .item-3 img {
    width: 300px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 20px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
    margin-left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;

}

#home .fade-up {
    top: 5px !important;
}

#home #slider .item-1 .absolute, #home #slider .item-2 .absolute, #home #slider .item-3 .absolute {
    font-family: Raleway-black;
    color: #a2a2a2;
    opacity: 0.33;
    position: absolute;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

#home #slider .item-1 .line-1 {
    bottom: -60px;
    right: 30px;
}

#home #slider .item-1 .line-2 {
    bottom: -100px;
    right: -10px;
}

#home #slider .item-2 .line-1 {
    bottom: -60px;
    right: 20px;
}

#home #slider .item-2 .line-2 {
    bottom: -100px;
    right: 0;
}

#home #slider .item-3 .line-1 {
    bottom: -60px;
    right: 50px;
}

#home #slider .item-3 .line-2 {
    bottom: -100px;
    right: 0;
}

#home #slider .item-2 {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

#home #slider .item-3 {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#home #dp-slider .dp_item:first-child {
    z-index: 10 !important;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px) !important;
}

#home #slider .dp_item[data-position="2"] {
    z-index: 9;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(10%) translateY(-15%) scale(0.9);
}

#home .transform {
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(10%) translateY(-15%) scale(0.9) !important;
}

#home #slider .dp_item[data-position="3"] {
    z-index: 8;
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(20%) translateY(-25%) scale(0.8);
}


#home #dp-dots {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    z-index: 12;
    right: 30px;
    cursor: default;
    padding: 0;
}

#home #dp-dots li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 9px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 3px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    cursor: pointer;
}

#home #dp-dots .first {
    height: 55px;
}

#home #dp-dots .second {
    height: 45px;
}

#home #dp-dots .third {
    height: 35px;
}

#home #dp-dots li.active {
    background: #cf132a;
}

#home #slider .dp_item {
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 750px;
    height: 280px;
}


#home #dp-slider .dp_item:hover:not(:first-child) {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home">
<div class="content-slider">
                <div class="text">
                    <div class="div div-1 is-active" data-class="1" data-position="1">
                        <h1>The New Hydra.VOX</h1>
                        <p>With state-of-the-art tech the VOX is the newest generation of Audiobyte D/A Converters, the
                            result of years of research.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="div div-2" data-class="2" data-position="2">
                        <h1>The New Hydra.HUB</h1>
                        <p>The next step towards the ultimate Audio Stack – the hub packs enhanced audio transport
                            capability with a set of digital tools for even the most demanding user.</p>
                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="div div-3" data-class="3" data-position="3">
                        <h1>The Hydra.ZAP Power Supply</h1>
                        <p>The ZAP is the dedicated, low-noise ultra-capacitor based power supply for the VOX HUB stack.
                            Attain supreme control over your digital equipment.</p>
     
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="slider">
                    <div class="dp-wrap">
                        <div id="dp-slider">
                            <div class="dp_item item-1" data-class="1" data-position="1">
                                <div class="dp-content opacity">
                                    <img class="fade-up" src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/6/Amplifier-PNG-File.png" alt="">
                                    <h1 class="absolute line-1">SUPREME IMMERSION</h1>
                                    <h1 class="absolute line-2">CONTEMPORARY DESIGN</h1>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dp_item item-2" data-class="2" data-position="2">
                                <div class="dp-content">
                                    <img class="fade-up" src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/6/Amplifier-PNG-File.png" alt="">
                                    <h1 class="absolute line-1">VERSATILITY</h1>
                                    <h1 class="absolute line-2">DIGITAL MASTERY</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="dp_item item-3" data-class="3" data-position="3">
                                <div class="dp-content">
                                    <img class="fade-up" src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/6/Amplifier-PNG-File.png" alt="">
                                    <h1 class="absolute line-1">HIGH PERFORMANCE</h1>
                                    <h1 class="absolute line-2">NO COMPROMISE</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <ul id="dp-dots">
                            <li data-class="1" class="active first"></li>
                            <li data-class="2" class="second"></li>
                            <li data-class="3" class="third"></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Now, this has a problem with the buttons, they don't work at all, were they even supposed to work ..?

Comment: I have removed the click events for simplicity. If you want to add the functionality, you already have a solution for that.